# Java Semaphore Thread Based Permit

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

I want to block threads with `Semaphore` *(or alternative)*. But same thread should not acquire multiple permit. For example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class ConcurencyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new ConcurencyTest().testSync(3);
        System.out.println("testSync finished");
        new ConcurencyTest().testSemaphore();
        System.out.println("testSemaphore finished");
    }

    public void testSemaphore() throws InterruptedException {
        final Semaphore s = new Semaphore(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            s.acquire();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void testSync(int i) {
        if (i == 0) return;
        System.out.println(i);
        testSync(i - 1);
    }

}
```

Output is:

```
3
2
1
testSync finished
0
1
--just waiting
```

Is there any alternative of Semaphore for continue at `--just waiting` row like `synchronized`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "But same thread should not acquire multiple permit." - Assuming a thread calls `.acquire()` method for your **custom semaphore** the second time, what behavior do you **want to achieve**? Should a method to just return, without updating the semaphore's counter? With a **single-threaded** code in the question post it is unclear why do you ever want to use semaphores or other synchronization mechanisms: these mechanisms are useful only in multi-threaded programs.

Comment: Method should not increment counter of semaphore until it call `.release()` method. For example you are trying to block multiple database connection per thread.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want a [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html), but that is just a guess since the question is bit unclear.